# Can 2GP Packages be deleted?

Tags: salesforcedx, second-generation-packaging

Due to limitations with extension packages and SFDX

- Must have a package installed to push extension code
- Inability to view debug logs from base when installed in extension SFDX org

we have had to use 2GP packages for the base and extension depending on the dev circumstances.

We are currently up to beta 245 lol.

Additionally, with multiple devs we have like 20 2GP packages due to lack of controls on creating them.

The question therefore: can an unreleased 2GP package be deleted at all?

The why: Clean up unneeded packages as it is to the point where all of the dead weight is starting to confuse the dev process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point, no. Packages, and package versions, cannot be deleted. There's an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lMYmQAM) you should go vote on. Note that you can deprecate packages, which does help with accidentally installing wrong versions, but for now, you'll have to live with your mistakes (by correcting them in a future version). Also, make sure you leave your feedback with the [DX team](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1) for any other future enhancements you'd like to see.

You can deprecate a version using the following DX command:

```
sfdx force:data:record:update -s Package2Version -i 05iXX000000XXXXXXX -v "IsDeprecated=true" -u DevHub -t
```

Comment: How do you deprecate a 2gp package? I did not see that in the list of packaging commands

Comment: Nevermind found it on the idea: `sfdx force:data:record:update -s Package2Version -i 05iXX000000XXXXXXX -v "IsDeprecated=true" -u DevHub -t`

Comment: @Eric I'll edit that in to the answer, too. You're right, it's worth being there.

Answer (score 1):

Just to say piggyback on sfdcfox's answer here to say package and package version deletion for 2GP is now possible after the feature was delivered in Winter '21. Note it's not possible with released packages/versions.

You'll get more info as well as the commands to delete in the Salesforce Docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_package_deletion.htm)